# OpenCV - detecting color ranges and display on console

Tags: python, colors, detection, opencv

So I have the following code and works fine when displaying the colors on a image. I know it uses a mask over the original image and only shows the colors which are defined in the declared boundaries. So basically it does not "detect" color, rather covers everything else which is not in the ranges.

usage: python code.py

An example image you can find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6XS5.jpg)

code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])


colors = {
    "red_lower" : "[  0   0 255]",
    "red_upper" : "[  0   0 127]",
    "blue_lower" : "[255  38   0]",
    "blue_upper" : "[255  38   0]",
    "yellow_lower" : "[  0 216 255]",
    "yellow_upper" : "[  0 216 255]",
    "gray_lower" : "[160 160 160]",
    "gray_upper" : "[160 160 160]"
}

boundaries = [
    ([0, 0, 255], [127, 0, 255]), #red
    ([255, 38, 0], [255, 38, 0]), #blue
    ([0, 216, 255], [0, 216, 255]), #yellow
    ([160, 160, 160], [160, 160, 160]) #gray
]

# loop over the boundaries
for (lower, upper) in boundaries:

    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = np.uint8)

    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

    # show the images
    cv2.imshow("Climbing Holds", np.hstack([image, output]))

    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am trying to catch the color on console through an If statement when matching one of the boundaries. If I compare directly with my colors dictionary wont work as expected, since all the boundaries go through the loop.

Example of If statement:

```
if str(lower) == colors["red_lower"]:
    print "red"
elif str(upper) == colors["red_upper"]:
    print "dark red"
elif str(lower) == colors["blue_lower"]:
    print "blue"
elif str(lower) == colors["yellow_lower"]:
    print "yellow"
elif str(lower) == colors["gray_lower"]:
    print "gray
```

I tried to debug by printing mask and output, but these return only zero tuples:

```
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

Does anyone know how to return the mask matching? Is it possible using cv2.imshow or cv2.read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine `colors` and `boundaries` into one object to iterate over. Combining the data is a good idea anyhow, as the lower/upper bounds are duplicated currently, once in `boundaries` and once as strings in the `colors` values. That duplication is not great, as it can lead to subtle errors. Some of the values already seem out of sync, so it's less error-prone to have them just in a single place.

```
color_boundaries = {
    "red":    ([0,   0,   255], [127, 0,   255]),
    "blue":   ([255, 38,  0],   [255, 38,  0]),
    "yellow": ([0,   216, 255], [0,   216, 255]),
    "gray":   ([160, 160, 160], [160, 160, 160])
}

for color_name, (lower, upper) in color_boundaries.items():
    # create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = np.uint8)

    # find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

    if mask.any():
        print(f"{color_name}: {mask.sum()}")
```

Comment: Hi w-m thanks for your contribution. Yeah that would be similar to my mentioned attempt with the If statements. The problem is that it will always output the other objects. Take for example this file https://imgur.com/a/L1tivfV
The problem I am facing is to determine which colors are present, but since the mask simply covers everything and shows only colors defined by the boundaries, it gets tricky. Maybe there is some other methods within OpenCV to do thr trick.

Comment: What exactly do you want to print?

Comment: Well I want to print just the colors which are actually on the picture. the second image above for example, it should print just the two and ignore the others declared. If the boundaries are not found, it wont print. Thats my question, whether its even possible using mask.

Comment: Yes sure. You could use any operations on the mask array, like `.any()` to test or `.sum()` to count. I've edited the answer with an example.

Comment: That works great, thank you!  
I wasn't aware of the .any() method. Just for curiosity, when printing mask right after the detection, why does it return zero matrices? Shouldn't it return a matrix based on the boundaries? Is it a property of the bitwise_and() method?
Output example: 

{'yellow': 16953165}

[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]

 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]

 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]

Comment: As the array is too large to print with the default print options, many values are left out from printing, being substituted by the ellipses. The ellipses just represent the fact that there are other values, which are not printed. They do not mean that all (non-printed) values are also zeros. Many of them are not.